# Rails nested attributes not validate on update association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a product class where I accepted rules attributes, and where rules are associated with choices.

Validations work very well in creating, the problem is when I remove the association rules with choices and it saves, and a rule is required to have at least a choice.

Below are the classes and the test in the terminal:

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { within: 3..25 }

  has_many :rules

  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :category_name, :rules_attributes, :disabled

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rules, allow_destroy: true
end
```

rule.erb

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { within: 3..40 }
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, only_integer: true }
  validates :choice_ids, presence: true

  belongs_to :product
  has_and_belongs_to_many :choices

  attr_accessible :name, :quantity, :choise_ids
end
```

terminal

```
irb(main):011:0> product = Product.find 2275
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2275]]
=> #<Product id: 2275, name: "Camarão", description: "", price: #<BigDecimal:623b7d8,'0.65E2',9(18)>, establishment_id: 2, created_at: "2013-10-17 18:37:26", updated_at: "2013-10-18 13:29:49", category_id: 333, disabled: false>

irb(main):012:0> rule = product.rules.find 333
  Rule Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "rules".* FROM "rules" WHERE "rules"."product_id" = 2275 AND "rules"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 333]]
=> #<Rule id: 333, name: "Adicionais", created_at: "2013-10-22 19:04:11", updated_at: "2013-10-22 19:04:11", quantity: 3, position: 0, product_id: 2275>

irb(main):013:0> rule.choice_ids = [""]
  Choice Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "choices".* FROM "choices" INNER JOIN "choices_rules" ON "choices"."id" = "choices_rules"."choice_id" WHERE "choices_rules"."rule_id" = 333
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> [""]

irb(main):014:0> rule.valid?
=> false

irb(main):015:0> rule.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000061b7780 @base=#<Rule id: 333, name: "Adicionais", created_at: "2013-10-22 19:04:11", updated_at: "2013-10-22 19:04:11", quantity: 3, position: 0, product_id: 2275>, @messages={:choice_ids=>["não pode ficar em branco"]}>

irb(main):016:0> product.rules_attributes = {"0"=>{"name"=>"Adicionais", "quantity"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"false", "choice_ids"=>[""], "id"=>"333"}}
  Rule Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "rules".* FROM "rules" WHERE "rules"."product_id" = 2275 AND "rules"."id" IN (333)
  Choice Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "choices".* FROM "choices" INNER JOIN "choices_rules" ON "choices"."id" = "choices_rules"."choice_id" WHERE "choices_rules"."rule_id" = 333
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> {"0"=>{"name"=>"Adicionais", "quantity"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"false", "choice_ids"=>[""], "id"=>"333"}}

irb(main):017:0> rule
=> #<Rule id: 333, name: "Adicionais", created_at: "2013-10-22 19:04:11", updated_at: "2013-10-22 19:04:11", quantity: 3, position: 0, product_id: 2275>

irb(main):018:0> rule.choices
=> []
```